# Detectar si la pantalla Android Wear, es cuadrada, circular o con franja

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-wear

¿Cómo se puede detectar que tipo de pantalla tiene el smartwatch en Android Wear de los tres tipos existentes?

- Rectangular `square`
- Circular `round`
- Circular con franja inferior (Moto360) `chin`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según la [documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/issues.html#ScreenShape).

```
private class Engine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine {
    boolean mIsRound;
    int mChinSize;

    @Override
    public void onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) {
        super.onApplyWindowInsets(insets);
        mIsRound = insets.isRound();
        mChinSize = insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom();
    }
    ...
}
```

También hay una forma no oficial https://github.com/tajchert/ShapeWear

En este segundo método, simplemente copia el fichero `ShapeWear.java` a tu proyecto e inicializalo en el `onCreate` del `mainActivity` así:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    ShapeWear.initShapeWear(this);
}
```

Especifica el `listener` de la siguiente manera:

```
ShapeWear.setOnShapeChangeListener(new ShapeWear.OnShapeChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void shapeDetected(ShapeWear.ScreenShape screenShape) {
        //Do your stuff here for example:
        switch (screenShape){
            case RECTANGLE:
                break;
            case ROUND:
                break;
            case MOTO_ROUND:
                //as it is special case of ROUND - cut at the bottom.
                break;
        }
    }
});
ShapeWear.setOnSizeChangeListener(new ShapeWear.OnSizeChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void sizeDetected(int widthPx, int heightPx) {
        //Do your stuff here
    }
});
```

Comment: Buen aporte, también veo que con la versión 23 (Android M) para wear, hay el sufijo -round y -notround